# How to do a Date range query using JDO on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, jdo, date-range, jdoql

Here is the code snippet I am trying to get to work:

```
final Query query = pm.newQuery("SELECT FROM model.Strip WHERE publishOn <= startDate
&& endDate >= publishOn PARAMETERS Date startDate, Date endDate import java.util.Date");
```

Since I am only querying on a single parameter, this should work according to the Google Docs.

> Inequality Filters Are Allowed on One
>   Property Only A query may only use
>   inequality filters (<, <=, >=, >, !=)
>   on one property across all of its
>   filters. For example, this query is
>   allowed:

```
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query.FilterOperator;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query.SortDirection;

Query q = new Query("Person");
q.addFilter("birthYear", FilterOperator.GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL, minBirthYearParam);
q.addFilter("birthYear", FilterOperator.LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL, maxBirthYearParam);
```

of course that is using the low-level Datastore interface, but I would expect that the JDO implementation just uses that as well.

But I am getting this un-helpful error message when I run my query.

> org.datanucleus.store.appengine.query.DatastoreQuery$UnsupportedDatastoreFeatureException:
>   Problem with query = publishOn
>   PARAMETERS Date startDate, Date
>   endDate import java.util.Date>:
>   Unexpected expression type while
>   parsing query:
>   org.datanucleus.query.expression.ParameterExpression

Does anyone know how to do a ranged query like this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out . . .

```
final Query query = pm.newQuery("SELECT FROM model.Strip WHERE publishOn <= startDate
&& endDate >= publishOn PARAMETERS Date startDate, Date endDate import java.util.Date");
```

changed to

```
final Query query = pm.newQuery("SELECT FROM model.Strip WHERE this.publishOn >= startDate
&& this.publishOn <= endDate PARAMETERS java.util.Date startDate, java.util.Date endDate");
```

you have to put the property before the variable, the `this.` doesn't hurt either

*I switched to Objectify so I would have to fight these stupid `JDO/JPA`semantics!*